# Repeated rows in 'connect by prior' clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to understand 'Connect by prior' clause in oracle.
I have created below table :
create table EMP_MGR
(
  mgr VARCHAR2(10),
  emp VARCHAR2(10)
)

Below is the data of table

```
MGR   EMP
null   f
f      a
f      b
f      c
b      x
b      y
```

Now, When I run the below query

```
select mgr,emp
from emp_mgr
connect by prior emp = mgr
start with mgr is null
```

Below is the output of above query:

```
MGR     EMP
null     f
f        a
f        b
b        x
b        y
f        c
```

I understand this output completely. but the problem is when I execute the same query without 'Start with' clause I am getting below output :

```
MGR     EMP
f       a
f       b
b       x
b       y
f       c
b       x
b       y
null    f
f       a
f       b
b       x
b       y
f       c
```

Please explain why the output is repeated. Why I am getting extra rows when I am not using start by clause

Comment: Did you try the Oracle documentation?

Comment: What do you think the `start with` clause does? If you understand what that is you'll understand why the results are different.

Comment: Start with clause specify the root from where I want to start

Comment: Right. So if you don't supply that, the query starts from every row and works down from each of them separately.. So as well as traversing `null->f->b->x` it will *also* traverse `f->b->x` and `b->x`.